# Ho to set acceptInsecureCerts for Firefox in Chimp.js framework?

Tags: firefox, webdriver-io, chimp.js

I'm automating a website and sometimes it uses an ip address as url, that ip address generates a connection is not secure message in Firefox. Researching online I found out that for Firefox, the default in chimp is acceptInsecureCerts = False. That doesn't happen to Chrome as the default is acceptInsecureCerts = True.

How can I change that in Chimp to make it also work in Firefox? Do I need to create a profile? If so, how can I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a WebdriverIO config than Chimp. See here how you can set `acceptInsecureCerts` using the `desiredCapabilities` section of the config like this:

```
module.exports {
  webdriverio: {
    desiredCapabilities: {
      browserName": "firefox",
      acceptInsecureCerts": true
    }
  }
}
```

The config above goes in the Chimp config file. [See here for details](https://chimp.readme.io/docs/command-line-options#section-using-a-configuration-file)

See the [full Chimp config here](https://github.com/xolvio/chimp/blob/master/src/bin/default.js)
See the [Webdriver.io config here](http://webdriver.io/guide/getstarted/configuration.html)
See the [desiredCapbilities support for webdriver here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities)

Note that browsers have their own extra desiredCapabilities, [like Chrome for example](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities).

Comment: It's a pleasure to see an answer from Xolv.io itself. Thanks! Could you give me more details, please? I'm using Chimp for less than one month now, so I'm kind of fresh. Where should I add that configuration? Chimp files or wdio? Once I modify that, will it overwrite information for all browsers or just for Firefox? Do I need to create new instances of the driver or may I continue using the browser command? (i.e. browser.click())

Comment: Updated the answer. How about now? :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to make it work now. I basically replicated the chimp.js file and added those entries above. So now, instead of running chimp --browser=firefox, I run chimp path_to_file/config-ff.js --browser=firefox. I haven't had to do any other changes so far in terms of Webdriver.io. In my package.json file, I have two entries under scripts: one called e2e when I don't want to pass a config file and another called e2e-firefox when I want to use Firefox with the proper config file settings.

Comment: Great to hear! Can you please mark this answer as correct?